# Fatal: master cannot be resolved to branch

Tags: github, push, fatal-error, git-bash

Here's a screenshot of what I'm dealing with:

[image] **I'm a new GitBash user** and am getting this error when trying to push to GitHub.

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWYqp7iY_Tc&t=1734s). So far I've not run into any problems, except I get this error when I try to push:

```
Fatal: master cannot be resolved to branch
```

Things I've done correctly:

- I am signed in
- I have specified my name and email using `git config -global... *blah blah*`
- Everything is committed and should be ready to push
- I'm on the master branch that I wish to push.
- I've added my remote repository using command `git remote add origin https://github.com/Tawnwen/MyApp.git`.
- I tried to push using the command `git push -u origin master`

Can anyone please help?

Comment: To help debug, could you post the output of executing `git branch`?

Comment: @vasilyrud It's already included in the linked image. However, with some tinkering now my "Master" branch is no longer currently highlighted in green.

Comment: Ah yes, it looks like you have a branch named `Master` instead of `master`. Try creating a new branch (and immediately switch to it) with `git checkout -b master` and then use that to push to Github with `git push -u origin master`.

Comment: @vasilyrud Hm.. the console is telling me that I already have a branch called `master`. Trying to do `git checkout master` tells me that I'm already in the master branch. I'm still getting the same error!

Comment: In that case, try following the answer given here (specifically about renaming `Master` to `master` in `.git/refs/heads`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034866/cant-push-to-remote-branch-cannot-be-resolved-to-branch/42802253

Comment: @vasilyrud Finally fixed after two days! Thanks so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't push to remote branch, cannot be resolved to branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034866/cant-push-to-remote-branch-cannot-be-resolved-to-branch)