# GIT: Commit only some changes to current branch and the rest to a new branch

Tags: git, github

Like an idiot, I made changes out of scope of my current branch.

I changed 5 files

```
 M  app/form_models/car_registration/basics.rb
M   app/form_models/car_registration/horse.rb
M   app/views/car_registration/basics.rb
M   app/views/car_registration/horse.html.erb
M   spec/factories/car.rb
M   spec/form_models/car_registration/basic_spec.rb
```

I would like to commit my basics.rb files to my branch, basics, and my horse.rb files to a new branch, horse.  I already did  git checkout -b horse, and all the files displayed. I have not committed yet. What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add the files you want to commit

`git add basics.rb`

and then commit

`git commit -m "your message"`

then stash changes

`git stash`

change branch

`git checkout -b new_branch`

Unstash changes

`git stash pop`

and commit all changes in your new branch

`git commit -am "commit message"`.

Cheers

Comment: I think it worked, but I also changed the name of the branch at the end and now getting fatal: feat/mvc/car-registration/horse cannot be resolved to branch. when I do git push --set-upstream origin feat/mvc/car_registration/horse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034866/cant-push-to-remote-branch-cannot-be-resolved-to-branch

Comment: Good answer, but the stash steps aren't necessary here. After the first commit, create the new branch as you did, then just add and commit again.